# How typescript infer the return type of a generic function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I get confused by this example from typescript's [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#push-type-parameters-down)

```js
function firstElement1<Type>(arr: Type[]) {
  return arr[0];
}
 
function firstElement2<Type extends any[]>(arr: Type) {
  return arr[0];
}
 
// a: number (good)
const a = firstElement1([1, 2, 3]);
// b: any (bad)
const b = firstElement2([1, 2, 3]);
```

According to the Typescript's handbook, the reason why `firstElement2` function infers the return type to be `any` is typescript has to resolve the `arr[0]` expression using the constraint type, rather than “waiting” to resolve the element during a call.

But if I change the first function `firstEelement1` to be:

```js
function firstElement1<Type extends number>(arr: Type[]) {
  return arr[0];
}
```

[image]

Why Typescript still infers this function's return type to be `Type` ?

Why Typescript doesn't infer this function's return type to be `number` ?

Comment: After you change the first function, `a` is inferred to be of type `1 | 2 | 3`. That is because you call it with `[1, 2, 3]`. If you're talking about the function definition, then the return value of `firstElement1<Type>` is of type `Type` which is correct, and even your original code infers it to be `Type`.

Comment: The caller gets to choose Type, not the implementation. You can call it with `firstElement1<1>([1])` and that should return `1`, not `number`.

Comment: "Why Typescript doesn't infer this function's return type to be number ?" because in addition to what pink mentions you could write `type Type = number & { a: string }` and it would work with your function if you passed an array of them and you wouldn't want it to lose type information. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oDsCuBbARhATlAZFAN5QCGA-AFxQDOwOAlsgOZQC+AUAGarIDGwBgHtkULkKEAeGFAgAPYBGQATGigzYcACjqouXajACUh4hyhQcEYKhyjd+gNwdOHPiLplD8KEgDMzqQAdKS+UADkABYM4W4ewFCYYeJCWqRGzu7INEIANhBBuULMWpghGVAA9JVQRUIA1lAAsqQANChCsjg4QjgAhBxAA

Answer (score -1):

The param 'arr' is an array of many Type elements, so the type of arr[0] is Type.
Anyway, 'Type' is the name of your generic:

```
const arr: number[] = [1,2,3];
const result = firstElement1(arr);
// result is 'number' because arr is 'number[]'
```

I can write it with explicit generic:

```
const arr: number[] = [1,2,3];
const result = firstElement1<number>(arr);
// result is 'number' because arr is 'number[]'
```